# Glide with android RecyclerView shows OutOfMemory Error (OOM)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, out-of-memory, android-glide

I am using Glide with RecyclerView to load many images (around 200) which have different sizes and dimensions.

I have three problems:

1. The images sometimes load successfully, and sometimes the app crashes giving OOM.
2. If the images are loaded successfully, then the scrolling is laggy.
3. If I refresh the layout and reload the same images, then it tries to load the images but fails before completion and gives OOM.

Following is the relevant code:

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {
            ImageView imageView = holder.imageView;
            Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
                    .load(tweetMapArray.get(listPosition).get("imageURL").toString())
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(imageView);
    // imageURL is a valid URL for each item
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(MyViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
        Glide.clear(holder.imageView);
    }
}
```

Please guide me as to what I am doing wrong. I have not worked with so many images before.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560637/out-of-memory-error-when-loading-more-images-in-glide

Answer (score 6):

I have found the cause. The problem was that I was using NestedScrollView placed above RecyclerView. This was probably causing all images to load at once.
I removed the NestedScrollView and requested around 200 images and it is working super smooth now.

Reference: [Out Of Memory Error When loading more images in Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560637/out-of-memory-error-when-loading-more-images-in-glide)

Thank you for writing replies. They are useful as well!

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy way to determine what is causing your `OutOfMemoryException` but there are ways to prevent it. Firstly, I would read [this issue](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/679#issuecomment-148194654) and then look into the [Memory Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory.html) features of Android Studio to determine whether anywhere else in your app is causing a memory leak.

Then, I would look at some of the image sizes and whether you need to determine it necassary to crop the images when they are being binded. The `.Override(width, height)` feature in Glide could assist you (width and height will be resized with pixels). Even further `.centerCrop()` and `.fitCenter()` could also help.

1. [Glide Image Resizing & Scaling](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-image-resizing-scaling)

If that doesn't help at all, I would suggest adding a Load More feature. So you only initially load a small sample of images and the user can then load more from there using either a button, when they scroll to the bottom or [SwipeRefreshLayout](http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/)

2. [LoadMore RecyclerView with ProgressBar tutorial - CodeTrick](https://codentrick.com/load-more-recyclerview-bottom-progressbar/)
3. [SwipeRefreshLayout tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lcBx4KVUVk)
4. [LoadMore Feature with RecyclerView implementation](https://gist.github.com/talenguyen/0a3d1e1f941a8a45adc2)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem always is with images, if they are high res there will be always OOM called. Also animation doesn't help especially within list/recycler views. Try to reduce image sizes, use separate ones for thumbs. I would better switch to Picasso than glide, because it has resize function which works pretty well and improves performance with large images dramatically.

Comment: Glide resizes before caching. Focus on the problem at hand.

Comment: ok so I limited the images to 100, and the app is now almost super smooth. I think that the error occurs when I request all images at the same time. I am looking at other solutions and will update if I find the solution for more images.