# OutOfMemoryError in Glide Image Loader

Tags: android

How to solve OutOfMemoryError in Glide Image Loading .

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 5137932
>   byte allocation with 923120 free bytes and 901KB until OOMSent on:2:54
>   threw uncaught 
>   throwablejava.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 5137932 byte
>   allocation with 923120 free bytes and 901KB until OOMat
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94)at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:164)at
>
> com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute(FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor.java:96)at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1121)at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)at
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor.java:118)Caused
>   by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 5137932 byte
>   allocation with 923120 free bytes and 901KB until OOMat
>   dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:882)at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:858)at
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.Downsampler.decodeStream(Downsampler.java:329)at
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.Downsampler.downsampleWithSize(Downsampler.java:220)at
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.Downsampler.decode(Downsampler.java:153)at
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.StreamBitmapDecoder.decode(StreamBitmapDecoder.java:50)at
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.StreamBitmapDecoder.decode(StreamBitmapDecoder.java:19)at
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageVideoBitmapDecoder.decode(ImageVideoBitmapDecoder.java:39)at
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageVideoBitmapDecoder.decode(ImageVideoBitmapDecoder.java:20)at
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gifbitmap.GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.decodeBitmapWrapper(GifBitmapWrapperResourceDe

**Glide Image Loder Code for loading Images**

```
Glide.with(activity)
            .load(items.get(position).getCharacterImageId(activity.getResources()))                   .placeholder(items.get(position).getColor(activity.getResources()))
                .dontAnimate()
                .thumbnail(0.7f)
                .into(img_letter);
```

Comment: Are you using emulator for testing?

Comment: We can't really help you without your code

Comment: I have used real device for testing.

Comment: can you show us code http://stackoverflow.com/a/31062339/4741746 check out this

Comment: reduce image size . add `.thumbnail(0.4f)` .Glide will display the original image reduced to 40% of the size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
```

**Use this line in your manifest file like :**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

If problem not solved then use this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
mBitmapInsurance = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath,options);
```

Comment: I have also used android:largeHeap="true".

Comment: I have Used glide so BitmapFactory option is not here,

Answer (score 0):

You can use **android:largeHeap="true"** to request a larger heap size, but this will not work on any pre Honeycomb devices. On pre 2.3 devices, you can use the VMRuntime class, but this will not work on Gingerbread and above.